# Add acctive state to buttons

Tags: html, css, button

I have a vertical navigation bar for web application control.
The navigation bar is used to be a selective toolbar.

So, except for normal and hover states of a button, there must be an Active state while a button is being pressed.

The Active state should let the pressed button change to darker background-color until other button be pressed.

How can I do that? is it possible to be done in CSS? or need jQuery?
I just tried  li:active in CSS but doesn't work.

Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
            <ul class="app_button" >
                <li><a href="XXX" class="app_button"><span>]</span>Function1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="app_button"><span>]</span>Function2</a></li>
                  <ul class="sub_app_button">
                   <li><a  href="aaa">subfunction1</a></li>
                   <li><a  href="bbb">subfunction2</a></li>
                   <li><a  href="ccc">subfunction3</a></li>
                   <li><a  href="ddd">subfunction4</a></li>
                  </ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="app_button"><span>]</span>Function3</a></li>
                  <ul class="sub_app_button">
                   <li><a  href="eee" >subfunction5</a></li>
                   <li><a  href="fff" >subfunction6</a></li>
                  </ul>
            </ul> <!-- end:app_button -->
        </div> <!-- end:navigation -->
```

Below is the CSS:

```
div.inner_page div.navigation  ul.app_button li{
   left:0;
   display: block;
   margin:0px;
   padding: 0;
}

div.inner_page div.navigation  ul.app_button li a 
{
    font-size:16px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 0px 6px 0px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #aaa;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-top:none;
}
div.inner_page div.navigation  ul.app_button li a:hover 
{    

    width: 150px;
    color: #9be163;
    background: #333333;
    top: 0px;
    border-bottom:none;
    border-top:none;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:active` pseudo selector:

```
div.inner_page div.navigation  ul.app_button li a:active
{    
    background: #111;/*whichever color you prefer*/
}
```

Now your button should have a darker background onClick :)

Comment: Hi, Kyle. Thanks!   But due to some reasons, the buttons were designed belong to div.inner_page. If one button pressed, the whole page would be refreshed. I must keep such button retain active state after the whole page refreshed. Is there any alternative way to do active state?

Comment: You'll probably have to do some backend fun to get that kind of functionality, not possible with standard HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

In order to acieve that you would have to assure that upon page refresh, the button is given an actual class of 'active' or similar and then style it properly. As Kyle wrote, this would have to rely on your cms, not css alone.